# Laravel - dropbox driver - This driver does not support retrieving URLs

Tags: dropbox, laravel-5.7

Using

Laravel 5.7

I'm trying to use dropbox driver to upload images , it works .. but when i want to get the url .. it gives me an error

```
This driver does not support retrieving URLs
```

### filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [

        'dropbox' => [
            'driver'     => 'dropbox',
            'app_secret' => env('DROPBOX_APP_SECRET'),
            'token'      => env('DROPBOX_TOKEN'),
        ],

    ],
```

### UploadController.php

```
public function postUpload(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $file = $request->file('picture');
        $filename=uniqid($user->id."_").".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Storage::disk('dropbox')->put($filename, File::get($file), 'public');

        $url = Storage::disk('dropbox')->url($filename);
        $user->profile_pic = $url;
        $user->save();

        $user->profile_pic = $filename;
        $user->save();
        return view('upload-complete')->with('filename', $filename)->with('url',$url);
}
```

### upload-complete.blade.php

```
@extends('template')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h1>File Uploaded</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="text-center">
       <img src="{{ $url }}" class="img-rounded" />
    </div>

</div>
@endsection
```